# Does Aspose.Total for .NET Supports .Net Core?

Tags: c#, aspose

Can someone help me out with the following questions please. Our team is trying to use Aspose.Total and have the following concerns

1. Does Aspose.Total for .NET support .NET core? If yes which version
2. Does Aspose.Total(version that supports .NET core) have all the features that may be in Aspose.Total full .NET Framework?
3. As Microsoft is moving to saying .NET 5(no more .net core after 3.1 or so) is it advisable to develop with Aspose.Total that currently support .net core? Or we should develop using .net full Aspose.Total version

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you ask them?

Comment: [The answer is really not hard to find on their website](https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsnet/System+Requirements#SystemRequirements-.NETFrameworks)

Comment: @PeterBons: Vendor tired their free support for the same and gone through the question posted but none on the answers were promising, clear, crisp & concise as mentioned by Nyerguds.

Comment: @Nyerguds Thanks for sharing the link. I think they should mention this link in their free support forum or anywhere such questions are asked.

Answer (score 3):

1. The short answer is yes, Aspose.Total supports .NET Core, the products included in Aspose.Total supports .NET Standard 2.0, so you can use them in .Net Core 2.0 or newer. Regarding version of Aspose.Total that supports .NET Core - you should note that Aspose.Total includes all Aspose products and some of them started to support .NET Core earlier some later. Aspose.Words for example support .NET Standard 2.0 starting from 17.12.0 version.
2. .NET Standard versions of Aspose products has some limitations. For example, Aspose.Words for .NET Standard does not support printing and saving to the client’s browser. Also, in case of using it in Linux environment it is required to install Linux Native assets for SkiaSharp. https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsnet/Xamarin+and+.NET+Standard+2.0+Limitations+and+API+Differences
   In addition to this Aspose.Words for .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET 4.6.1 supports reading PDF documents; this feature is not supported in earlier .NET framework versions.
3. Microsoft recommends to use .NET Core and then .NET 5 to develop new applications. So, I would recommend to follow their recommendations. Both .NET and .NET Standard versions of Aspose products use the common codebase (with minor differences). So both will give you the same set of core features.